# perl sudo using Net::Openssh not working

Tags: perl, sudo

I am using salvas' Net::Openssh module, but not able to figure how to use sudo. I have tried the following, but it is not working...

There is nothing printed in results. Single word commands like `ls`, `pwd` are also not producing anything.

version of sudo on target system:

```
$ /usr/local/bin/sudo -V
CU Sudo version 1.5.7p2

$ /usr/local/bin/sudo -h
CU Sudo version 1.5.7p2
usage: /usr/local/bin/sudo -V | -h | -l | -v | -k | -H | [-b] [-p prompt] [-u username/#uid] -s | <command>
```

since CU sudo does not allow more than 1 option at a time, i supply -k before supplying the command.

please note that this sudo version does not have -S switch to pass password using stdin. so it expects password from terminal. can u pl help more. thx.

```
$ssh->system("$sudo_path -k");
my @output = $ssh->capture({tty => 1,
              stdin_data => "$PASS"},
              $sudo_path,
              "-p",'', "$cmd");
print "  result=@output \n";
```

OR

```
$ssh->system("$sudo_path -k");
my @output = $ssh->capture({stdin_data => "$PASS"},
              $sudo_path,
              "-p",'', "$cmd");
print "  result=@output \n";
```

Comment: Are you trying to run a command that requires you to use sudo over your Net::OpenSSH connection? If so, you should modify your question title to more accurately reflect your issue 'perl sudo...' sounds like you're trying to use the Perl Sudo module http://search.cpan.org/~landman/Sudo-0.21/lib/Sudo.pm

Comment: Hello Andrew, I am going to checkout sudo.pm I will report back what  find. if you have any usage experience pl share

Comment: that may work as sudo.pm seems to provide some remote mechanism, though it hasn't been updated since 2007. As always with perl - timtowtdi. Whatever works best for you, I just answered what seemed the most simple to me and required the least dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

It would be more helpful if you explained more of what you were trying to accomplish in your question, but I'm assuming you're trying to run a command that requires sudo via ssh using the Net::OpenSSH module in perl.

If that is the case, you should consider trying a 'heredoc' to script a series of commands.

Here is the [PerlDoc for Quote-Like operators](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators) - look for the area talking about `<<EOF` as I've often used [here docs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document) to script things like this.

If for some reason using a heredoc within the Net::OpenSSH command doesn't work - Net::OpenSSH also works with Expect as documented [here](http://search.cpan.org/~salva/Net-OpenSSH-0.57/lib/Net/OpenSSH.pm#Expect).

And if for some reason that doesn't work for you, you could always create a shell script that runs the command with sudo via a heredoc on the remote system, and just execute that script via your Net::OpenSSH connection.

Comment: question is how to pass password to sudo. once sudo auth is done running the command would not be difficult. can you pass password with HERE doc??

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't - but try it yourself. Create a 'heredoc' in a scalar, and pass that to your Net::OpenSSH connection via ```$ssh->system()```.
If it doesn't work though, I've listed other options that will solve your problem as well - such as using your ssh connection to execute a shell script on the remote server that could contain a heredoc to execute things as sudo. I've also mentioned the fact that Net::OpenSSH works with expect, which is often used to supply passwords to things.

Comment: i have tried using expect earlier, which also is not working properly. i posted a question on that also....